# How can I achieve the following reaction where the iodide gets replaced by an aldehyde?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

The question is what other chemicals need to be added so that the reaction is possible.

Although the solution shouldnt be that hard, I couldnt find the answer to this one.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Through the good graces of @Waylander, you received a correct answer. Your question will likely be considered as homework and be voted down. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself. Take a look here about homework policy. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the reaction adds a carbon to the struture.
This can be done in two steps:

1. React the iodide with NaCN or KCN in DMSO to form the nitrile
2. Reduce the nitrile to the aldehyde with di-isobutylaluminium hydride [Dibal-H](https://commonorganicchemistry.com/Rxn_Pages/Nitrile_to_Aldehyde/Nitrile_to_Aldehyde_Index.htm)